# Can't success to fetch list of data in frontend

Tags: polkadot-js, ink

This is Contract code to return List of TodoItem:

```
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn gettodolist(&self) -> Vec<TodoItem> {
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            let mut item: Vec<TodoItem> = Vec::new();
            for _item in 0..self.item_id {
                match self.item.get(_item) {
                    Some(value) => {
                        if value.owner == caller {
                            item.push(value);
                        }
                    }
                    None => (),
                }
            }
            item
        }
```

and on polkadotjs this function return todos as follows:

[image]

I use this code to get list of todos in front end. It's response is success but it doesn't return value it gives array 0.

```
const { gasRequired, result, output } = await contract.query.gettodolist(
      address,
      {
        gasLimit,
        storageDepositLimit,
      }
    );

    // const result = await api.call.contractsApi.call(address, contract.address, 0, null, null, msg.toU8a(msg.args.map((_) => account.address)))

    // The actual result from RPC as `ContractExecResult`
    console.log(result.toHuman());

    // the gas consumed for contract execution
    console.log(gasRequired.toHuman());

    // check if the call was successful
    if (result.isOk) {
      // output the return value
      console.log("This is Success", output?.toHuman());
```

[image]

Can you suggest me anything how to get list of data in Frontend?

Comment: Take a look at what polkadot apps does in [valueToText](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/c80b14e620ca42f97055ca572da52ae1eceaa91b/packages/react-params/src/valueToText.tsx). These are the functions used to display the call outcomes.

Comment: Are you calling from the same account when you run the code in your own UI?

Comment: yeah I am using same account

Comment: Are you definitely calling the same contract in each case?

Comment: Yeah you can view in this code https://github.com/substrate-dapps/todo-dapp/tree/main/ui

Answer (score 1):

The ink! documentation on [Contract Debugging](https://use.ink/basics/contract-debugging/) should be helpful here.

You could e.g. add a `ink::env::debug_println!("item: {:?}", _item);` statement in your loop to see if there even is any iteration happening. The output will be visible on your shell, for the `substrate-contracts-node -lerror,runtime::contracts=debug` process.